# What happens to a great mathematician's unpublished works when they die?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, mathematicians

When a great mathematician dies, they often leave plenty of unpublished and incomplete works in their manuscripts. As we assumed that they were a really good mathematician, most of the ideas in these documents could be very interesting and helpful to others in the community even if they are sketchy or incomplete.

> **Question:** What to do in this situation? Is there any legal and copy-right preserving way to publish incomplete ideas, proofs and manuscripts of a dead mathematician? How should this be done? Are there historical examples of such a case?

Comment: The same thing that happens to anything else owned by said mathematician. It passes on with the rest of the estate. Whatever they do with it is a different story altogether.

Comment: Well, there was that one incident with [Galois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89variste_Galois#Final_days) being on the wrong side of a duel. His unpublished papers did alright though.

Comment: Also, a mandatory joke that mathematicians don't die, their existence just becomes contradictory. Or mathematicians don't die, they become part of the empty set. Or some other related joke. :-)

Comment: See the “About Me” section of my profile. :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian I read it. It is really interesting. What is the relation between Martin Luther's picture and Joshua King's story in your profile (if there is any)?! ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila A glimpse to set theory community shows that we have a list of brilliant history-maker set theorists who the sum of their ages exceeds a large cardinal! I think it is not bad if someone organizes a program or a website for collecting their unpublished papers and manuscripts in order to preserve these valuable documents. Regardless to the scientific benefits of this project for other researchers it may have some historical value too.

Comment: Uhm, none. I've seen some cartoons when I was little about the history of Europe, and was impressed by Luther's persona. And the quote fits with my dark sense of humor. :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian "Empty" is a relation itself!

Comment: Ali, it will be decades before we finish deciphering Shelah's work. The one that got published by 2014 anyway.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well, but I think the math community really needs such a protection project. A small international NGO can be organized by some colleagues. It can invite all great mathematicians around the world to register in this "math museum" project in order to add their incomplete manuscripts to an online encyclopedia-like website, after their retirement. I think it is just a matter of scanning some papers and uploading some files. Why not? Anybody can collaborate with the project in his own region. For example you can talk to Magidor, Shelah, Gitik, somebody talks to Woodin, Jensen, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I did was post the unpublished stuff on a website; this included collecting copies of some items from some thirty or forty years earlier that had been requested of me. On the other hand, his children (grown) have quite a bit as well.

The most important case of this is Riemann. The collection of papers is usually called by the German word, [Nachlass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachlass). The reason we have the [Riemann Siegel formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_formula) is that Siegel was able to go through Riemann's Nachlass. That was in a major university library, probably the best location. More complete story in [EDWARDS](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486417409.html).

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I think the idea of organizing a website for keeping retired mathematicians unpublished manuscripts safe and recorded is very nice and useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ramanujan's unpublished notebooks were miraculously preserved, published, and gone through, producing some amazing math.